Cookie или Localstorage
В приложении нужно хранить такие данные как: язык, тему, например, и где лучше всего хранить эти данные ? Всегда использовал LocalStorage, но мне кажется это не верное решение, в базу данных может, но тогда каждый раз с базы грузить, а идентификационную информацию где хранить тогда ? Не каждый же раз просить пользователя зайти. Что лучше всего использовать ?

Для хранения какой информации о самом клиенте (тема, локализация, открытое меню и т.д.) лучше хранить в localStorage.
Разница между localStorage и Cookie в том, что Cookie автоматически "креплятся" в заголовки запросов и отправляются на сервер. Они случат для передачи технической информации о запросе.
В додачу к этому, сервер не имеет доступа к localStorage, что так же стоит учесть. Т.е., это хранилище чисто для клиента.
Теперь по вопросу. Тему, язык и т.д., обычно хранят в localStorage. Токены, ключи, идентификаторы, т.е., всё что вам нужно для выполнения запросов - в Cookie
На счёт идентификаторов. Такую информацию желательно так же хранить в куках. Те же токены или авторизационные куки сразу будут отправляться на сервер для проверки авторизации сервером
